# Error with renaming of columns after producing data frame with aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate, rename

I do not understand why the column names of a data frame produced by the aggregate function cannot be renamed correctly?

I use the aggregate function to make some summary statistics by groups. In the following I present a reproducible example.

```
> data <- read.table(header=T, text='
+  subject sex condition before after change
+        1   F   placebo   10.1   6.9   -3.2
+        2   F   placebo    6.3   4.2   -2.1
+        3   M   aspirin   12.4   6.3   -6.1
+        4   F   placebo    8.1   6.1   -2.0
+        5   M   aspirin   15.2   9.9   -5.3
+        6   F   aspirin   10.9   7.0   -3.9
+        7   F   aspirin   11.6   8.5   -3.1
+        8   M   aspirin    9.5   3.0   -6.5
+        9   F   placebo   11.5   9.0   -2.5
+       10   M   placebo   11.9  11.0   -0.9
+       11   F   aspirin   11.4   8.0   -3.4
+       12   M   aspirin   10.0   4.4   -5.6
+       13   M   aspirin   12.5   5.4   -7.1
+       14   M   placebo   10.6  10.6    0.0
+       15   M   aspirin    9.1   4.3   -4.8
+       16   F   placebo   12.1  10.2   -1.9
+       17   F   placebo   11.0   8.8   -2.2
+       18   F   placebo   11.9  10.2   -1.7
+       19   M   aspirin    9.1   3.6   -5.5
+       20   M   placebo   13.5  12.4   -1.1
+       21   M   aspirin   12.0   7.5   -4.5
+       22   F   placebo    9.1   7.6   -1.5
+       23   M   placebo    9.9   8.0   -1.9
+       24   F   placebo    7.6   5.2   -2.4
+       25   F   placebo   11.8   9.7   -2.1
+       26   F   placebo   11.8  10.7   -1.1
+       27   F   aspirin   10.1   7.9   -2.2
+       28   M   aspirin   11.6   8.3   -3.3
+       29   F   aspirin   11.3   6.8   -4.5
+       30   F   placebo   10.3   8.3   -2.0
+  ')
> 
> summary.function <- function(x){c(mean(abs(x)),mean(x),min(x),max(x))}
> data.summary <- aggregate(data=data,change~condition+sex,FUN=summary.function)
> data.summary
  condition sex  change.1  change.2  change.3  change.4
1   aspirin   F  3.420000 -3.420000 -4.500000 -2.200000
2   placebo   F  2.058333 -2.058333 -3.200000 -1.100000
3   aspirin   M  5.411111 -5.411111 -7.100000 -3.300000
4   placebo   M  0.975000 -0.975000 -1.900000  0.000000
> colnames(data.summary) <- c("condition","sex","absmean","mean","min","max")
```

> ```
> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("condition", "sex", "absmean",  : 
>   'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [3]
> ```

The `colnames()` function gets the wrong column names:

```
> colnames(data.summary)
```

> ```
> [1] "condition" "sex"       "change"
> ```

Can somebody help me?

Edit:
after trying other packages than in the r base, it also worked for

`library(doBy) 
data.summary <- summaryBy(change ~ sex + condition, data=data, FUN=summary.function) colnames(data.summary) <- c("condition","sex","absmean","mean","min","max")`

Comment: aggregate can output a matrix. Try `str(data.summary)` and you'll likely see that it doesn't have as many columns as you think.

Comment: You can do `data.summary <- do.call(data.frame, data.summary)`  and change the names

Comment: @PierreLafortune: the output is a data frame

Comment: @sebastiann You check the `str(data.summary)` as PierreLafortune mentioned, you will have only 3 columns

Comment: See akrun's answer for more clarity. There is a two-dimensional array embedded in the data frame, which isn't expected from users.

Comment: @akrun: thanks, that is working! `data.summary <- do.call(data.frame, data.summary)` before renaming the column

Comment: after trying other packages than in the r base, it also worked for `library(doBy)
data.summary <- summaryBy(change ~ sex + condition, data=data, FUN=summary.function)
colnames(data.summary) <- c("condition","sex","absmean","mean","min","max")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'the 'condition', 'sex', columns, we apply the `summary.function` to 'change' and convert to `list`.  The advantage is that in the output, we get 6 columns instead of the `matrix` output in `aggregate` (as mentioned by @PierreLafortune in the comments) i.e. a data.frame with 2 regular columns and one `matrix` column (which we can convert to a regular `data.frame` by using `do.call(data.frame, ..`) . Also, we can name the functions directly in the `summary.function` (I changed the `summary.function` slightly).  Even if we use the modified `summary.function`, the `aggregate` columns will have `change.` prefix attached to the column names which we may need to change it later.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, as.list(summary.function(change)) , by = .(condition, sex)]
#   condition sex  absmean      mean  min  max
#1:   placebo   F 2.058333 -2.058333 -3.2 -1.1
#2:   aspirin   M 5.411111 -5.411111 -7.1 -3.3
#3:   aspirin   F 3.420000 -3.420000 -4.5 -2.2
#4:   placebo   M 0.975000 -0.975000 -1.9  0.0
```

where

```
summary.function <- function(x){c(absmean=mean(abs(x)),mean=mean(x),
                          min=min(x),max=max(x))}
```

---

Here is the problem in the `aggregate` output.

```
data.summary <- aggregate(data=data, change~condition+sex,FUN=summary.function)
str(data.summary)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ condition: Factor w/ 2 levels "aspirin","placebo": 1 2 1 2
# $ sex      : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 2 2
# $ change   : num [1:4, 1:4] 3.42 2.058 5.411 0.975 -3.42 ...
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ : NULL
# .. ..$ : chr  "absmean" "mean" "min" "max"
```

Here, we have only 3 columns, and the 3rd column 'change' is a `matrix`.  We can convert to a regular `data.frame`

```
data.summary <- do.call(data.frame, data.summary)
str(data.summary)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  6 variables:
#$ condition     : Factor w/ 2 levels "aspirin","placebo": 1 2 1 2
#$ sex           : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 2 2
#$ change.absmean: num  3.42 2.058 5.411 0.975
#$ change.mean   : num  -3.42 -2.058 -5.411 -0.975
#$ change.min    : num  -4.5 -3.2 -7.1 -1.9
#$ change.max    : num  -2.2 -1.1 -3.3 0
```

Change the column names by removing the prefix part

```
names(data.summary) <- sub('[^.]+\\.', '', names(data.summary))
```